# Symfony, clear:cache "Failed to remove directory " on Vagrant

Tags: symfony, caching, vagrant

I've a problem when I clear the cache in a Vagrant VM. Here a part of the config file :

```
synced_folder:
    vflsf_19mkvk0x71hk:
        source: /var/www/vm/vmnginx
        target: /var/www
        sync_type: default
        smb:
            smb_host: ''
            smb_username: ''
            smb_password: ''
            mount_options:
                dir_mode: '0775'
                file_mode: '0664'
        rsync:
            args:
                - '--verbose'
                - '--archive'
                - '-z'
            exclude:
                - .vagrant/
                - .git/
                - vendor/
            auto: 'true'
        owner: vagrant
        group: www-data
```

The error message tell me it can't be possible to remove a folder :

```
$ sfconsole cache:clear -vv
22:46:17 INFO      [php] User Deprecated: The "Symfony\Component\Console\Event\ConsoleExceptionEvent" class is deprecated since version 3.3 and will be removed in 4.0. Use the ConsoleErrorEvent instead. ["exception" => Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException {trace: { …} …}] []


  [Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]                                       
  Failed to remove directory "/var/www/formation/symfony-blog/var/cache/de~/translations": . 


Exception trace:
 () at /var/www/formation/symfony-blog/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:176
 Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem->remove() at /var/www/formation/symfony-blog/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:172
 Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem->remove() at /var/www/formation/symfony-blog/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/CacheClearCommand.php:70
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand->execute() at /var/www/formation/symfony-blog/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:264
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/formation/symfony-blog/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:887
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/formation/symfony-blog/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:223
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/formation/symfony-blog/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:81
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/formation/symfony-blog/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:130
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/formation/symfony-blog/bin/console:28

cache:clear [--no-warmup] [--no-optional-warmers] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>
```

I've add the "vagrant" user in the "www-data" group.

Folder :

```
$ ll var/cache/
total 16K
drwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant www-data 4,0K juil.  8 22:43 ./
drwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant www-data 4,0K juil.  7 16:01 ../
drwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant www-data 4,0K juil.  8 22:43 de~/
drwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant www-data 4,0K juil.  8 22:43 dev/
```

Here the "real" folder outside the VM :

```
✔ /var/www/vm/vmnginx/formation/symfony-blog [master {origin/master}|✚ 9] 
11:10 $ ll var/cache/
total 16K
drwxrwxr-x 4 fabrice fabrice 4,0K juil.  9 09:56 ./
drwxrwxr-x 5 fabrice fabrice 4,0K juil.  7 16:01 ../
drwxrwxr-x 3 fabrice fabrice 4,0K juil.  9 09:56 de~/
drwxrwxr-x 7 fabrice fabrice 4,0K juil.  9 09:56 dev/
```

And, I can't change the permissions, even in with sudo. There's no error message, but nothing happend.

The "rm -fr var/cache" works.

Can u help me please.

Fabrice

Comment: Pleashe show `ll var/cache/de~/` output

Answer (score 0):

In must case this is drasticaly the last treatment, but its work. Have a look there :

https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html#using-acl-on-a-system-that-supports-setfacl-linux-bsd

Comment: Hi, Thanks for help. I try using ACL. The HTTPDUSER is set to "www-data". But, the two commands "setfacl" (with sudo) return "Operation not supported" for all the files.

Comment: Sudo is Just the curent user with root grant, you Can use sudo by install it and add crurent user to sudo groupe or you Can run the commandes as root by remplace whoami (and '') by your curent username

Comment: Hi. I've again the same message "Operation not supported" :(. I've set HTTPDUSER=vagrant, and run the setfacl command : same issue. I've read that I must set the "acl" in fstab (on the partition shared), it's true ?

Comment: Same problem trying to chmod 777 in the web/uploads folder (using Uploadable with DoctrineExtensions) :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ll var/cache/de~
total 1,3M
drwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant www-data 4,0K juil.  9 09:56 ./
drwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant www-data 4,0K juil.  9 09:56 ../
-rwxrwxr-- 1 vagrant www-data 130K juil.  8 22:43 appDevDebugProjectContainerCompiler.log*
-rwxrwxr-- 1 vagrant www-data 459K juil.  9 09:56 appDevDebugProjectContainer.php*
-rwxrwxr-- 1 vagrant www-data  26K juil.  9 09:56 appDevDebugProjectContainer.php.meta*
-rwxrwxr-- 1 vagrant www-data 365K juil.  8 22:43 appDevDebugProjectContainer.xml*
-rwxrwxr-- 1 vagrant www-data 314K juil.  8 22:43 classes.php*
drwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant www-data 4,0K juil.  9 09:56 pools/
```

and

```
$ ll var/cache/de~/pools/
total 8,0K
drwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant www-data 4,0K juil.  9 09:56 ./
drwxrwxr-x 1 vagrant www-data 4,0K juil.  9 09:56 ../
```